# Android 5.0, how to scroll grid to a fixed position using Etsy StaggeredGridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, staggered-gridview

i've been working with [Etsy's StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) for a while, and i'm quite happy with it, but now i have a problem which i am not able to solve. I need to scroll to a fixed position (in pixels or in adapter position) within the list and i am using this (yes, the position is just under the header as you can see):

```
gridView.scrollListBy(header.getHeight());
```

in addition, the smooth scroll methods such as smoothScrollBy(int, int) aren't supported by this kind of gridview. Everything was working ok, but a pair of days ago i updated one of the devices that i use for testing (a Nexus 7) to Android 5.0.2 version (from 4.4) and now that method is no longer working, giving me this exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void android.widget.AbsListView.fillGap(boolean)"
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4968)
at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollListBy(AbsListView.java:4785)
```

i would like to know why its working in Android 4.4 and giving this error in Android 5.0, it seems quite weird for me, and if you have any solution i would really apreciate them, thank you very much for your time